# ECL nested folders

Tags: ecl

When building an ECL Provider we are trying to have nested folders (a folder within a folder, just like on a file system).  We have implemented a `GetFolderContent` method and this is firing when we click on the first level folder within the mount point - our items are showing up in the CME and one of those items is a Folder.  However, when we click on this second-level folder the `GetItem` and `GetItems` methods are fired, but `GetFolderContent` is not, so nothing happens in the CME when we try to drill down.

What is the chain of method calls when we click on a nested folder, and which method is responsible for showing the list of items in a nested Folder?

Answer (score 9):

For starters it is important that you implement all of these methods correctly, and that you have a clear definition of what is a `EclItemTypes.File` and what is a `EclItemTypes.Folder`.

Let me try to explain based on my [Flickr ECL provider](https://code.google.com/p/sdl-tridion-world/source/browse/Flickr+ECL+Provider/trunk/Flickr+ECL+Provider) example, the `IContentLibraryContext.FindItem(IEclUri)` I chose to return `null`, which basically forces ECL to call `IContentLibraryContext.GetItem(IEclUri)` instead.

`IContentLibraryContext.GetItem(IEclUri)` makes sure the correct `ItemType` is being returned:

```cs
public IContentLibraryItem GetItem(IEclUri eclUri)
{
  if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File && eclUri.SubType == "img")
  {
    return new FlickrPhoto(...);
  }

  if (eclUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.Folder && eclUri.SubType == "set")
  {
    return new FlickrPhotoSet(...);
  }

  throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

This provider only has two item types (`IContentLibrary.DisplayTypes`), if it would support more, the above method would have more conditions (you might want to separate them out in a private method which you call from `IContentLibraryContext.GetItem(IEclUri)`).

`IContentLibraryContext.GetItems(IList<IEclUri>)` is there to filter out duplicates from BluePrinted Publications for instance.

```cs
public IList<IContentLibraryItem> GetItems(IList<IEclUri> eclUris)
{
  List<IContentLibraryItem> items = new List<IContentLibraryItem>();
  IEnumerable<string> uniquePhotoIds = (from uri in eclUris
                                        where uri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File 
                                        && uri.SubType == "img"
                                        select uri.ItemId).Distinct();

  foreach (string id in uniquePhotoIds)
  {
    string itemId = id;
    var urisForPhoto = from uri in eclUris
                       where uri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.File 
                       && uri.SubType == "img" && uri.ItemId == itemId
                       select uri;

    foreach (IEclUri eclUri in urisForPhoto)
    {
      items.Add(GetItem(eclUri));
    }
  }
  return items;
}
```

Then last in `IContentLibraryContext.GetFolderContent(IEclUri, int, EclItemTypes)` you determine what to show, `Folders` and `Files`, or just `Folders` (when a `Folder` is opened in the tree view for example).

```cs
public IFolderContent GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, int pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
{
  List<IContentLibraryListItem> items = new List<IContentLibraryListItem>();

  if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.MountPoint &&
      itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.Folder))
  {
    // get photosets
    foreach (FlickrInfo info in Provider.Flickr.GetPhotoSets())
    {
      items.Add(new ListItem(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, info));
    }
  }
  // only return files if they are requested (itemTypes is EclItemTypes.File))
  else if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.Folder && 
           parentFolderUri.SubType == "set" && 
           itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.File))
  {
    // get photos
    foreach (FlickrInfo info in Provider.Flickr.GetPhotosInSet(parentFolderUri.ItemId))
    {
      items.Add(new ListItem(parentFolderUri.PublicationId, info));
    }
  }

  return Provider.HostServices.CreateFolderContent(parentFolderUri, items, false, false);
}
```

As you can see, this method only deals items of type `IContentLibraryListItem`, these are so called unloaded items, just containing basic properties like title and modified date.

Now my `IContentLibraryContext.GetFolderContent(IEclUri, int, EclItemTypes)` example is rather limited, it expects only a basic structure and no folders below it. If you have a more complex structure you will probably want to use something like:

```cs
public IFolderContent GetFolderContent(IEclUri parentFolderUri, int pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes)
{
  List<IContentLibraryListItem> items = new List<IContentLibraryListItem>();
  bool flag = itemTypes.HasFlag(EclItemTypes.File);
  string id = parentFolderUri.ItemId;
  int pub = parentFolderUri.PublicationId;

  if (parentFolderUri.ItemType == EclItemTypes.MountPoint)
  {
    // get base structure
    items.AddRange(GetMyItems(null, flag).Select(info => new ListItem(pub, info)));
  }
  else
  {
    // get items in folder
    items.AddRange(GetMyItems(id, flag).Select(info => new ListItem(pub, info)));
  }

  return Provider.HostServices.CreateFolderContent(parentFolderUri, items, false, true);
}
```

Where you handle getting the correct set of items (`Folders` only or `Folders` and `Files`) in a private method called `GetMyItems` (or whatever you want).

Also note I ignored pagination, else you will need to do something with `pageIndex` and use an overload of `CreateFolderContent`.